# Making an Alert apper after a certain amount of lanuches

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uialertview, alert

I am working on this idea where I want an UIAlert to pop up after a certain amount of launches of the app (let's say after 20 launches).

And there's going to be 2 buttons. One that will reset the counter which will make the alert appear after another 20 launches.
And one button that will make it disappear and never appear again.

How I would do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your AppDelegate `applicationDidFinishLaunching:withOptions:` method check `NSUserDefaults`:

```
int counter = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"LaunchesCounter"];
if (counter == -1)
{ /* Cancel chekcing, cause earlier user choose hide alert */ }
else if (counter >= 20)
{ /* Show alert */ }
else // Increment counter
{
    ++counter;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:counter forKey:@"LaunchesCounter"];
}
```

If user choose continue to show alert rewrite counter with 0:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:0 forKey:@"LaunchesCounter"];
```

If user choose to hide alerts set counter to -1:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:-1 forKey:@"LaunchesCounter"];
```

Comment: Could you please look at my code and see if I've done anything wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at NSUserDefaults to store a count of the number of times the app has started.

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
uint count = [defaults integerForKey:@"num_launches"];

if (count > 20) {
    // Show alert
} else {
   count ++;
   [defaults setInteger:count forKey:@"num_launches"];
}
```

Comment: You do not define that user cancel alerting forever

Comment: No - I haven't done his work for him, I've shown him how to use NSUserDefaults :)  (*assuming inFever is a he)

Answer (score 1):

Set up a counter. Increment it each time the app launches and store it in `NSUserDefaults`. Check it each time to make sure it is less than 20. If it is equal to 20 then reset and store again.
This helps to get launch count

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSInteger launchCount = [prefs integerForKey:@"launchCount"];
if (launchCount > limit) {
     // Show alert
} else {
 launchCount ++;
 [prefs setInteger:count forKey:@"launchCount"];
}

launchCount++;
NSLog(@"Application has been launched %d times", launchCount);
[prefs setInteger:launchCount  forKey:@"launchCount"];
```